# url input field validating on the client, but none of the other fields are

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails application, using Devise for users registration/management.

In my user model, I have the following:

```
validates :first, presence: true
validates :last, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
validates :url, format: {with: NO_SPACES_REGEX}, presence: true
```

When filling out the form, if I do not fill the url field, and submit the form, I get the following message (balloon pointing to the url entry box):

Please enter a URL.

This happens on the client side. If the URL field is filled in the form, and any of the other required fields, the form submits, and then I get messages in a separate red box asking me to enter the missing values.

Any idea why the url field is the only one validating locally, pre form submission, but none of the other forms are?

The only other unique thing about this field is that it has a value assigned to it in the form:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label"><%= f.label :url, URL_STR %></div>
  <div class="controls"><%= f.url_field :url, :value => "http://", :class => "request-text-line" %></div>
</div>
```

None of the other fields have a value assigned to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is in the **type** of the field. If you look in the source code in the browser, you will see that the type is "url". There are a number of types in hltm5 that trigger client side validations. Partial list is **email, url, number, tel, date**, but there are more. You triggered this by using **url_field**, which caused the type to be "url", resulting in client-side validation. The normal text fields don't do this of course (can't do this). But e.g., for your email field you could so something similar by using **email_field**

If you want to read more on this, I can refer you to http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/